# activeTab.url Safari extension

Tags: javascript, google-translate, safari-extension

I'm trying to create an extension to translate a web page using google translate.
I compose url like: `url google translate + current tab + &sl=auto&tl=it&hl=&ie=UTF-8` but doesn't work. What's wrong?

Thank you

```
<script>
safari.application.addEventListener("command", performCommand, false);

function performCommand(event) {
    if (event.command == "translate") {     
        var currentTab.url = safari.application.activeBrowserWindow.currentTab.url;     
        var rUrl = "http://translate.google.it/translate?u=" +  encodeURIComponent(currentTab.url) + "&sl=auto&tl=it&hl=&ie=UTF-8";     
        safari.application.activeBrowserWindow.activeTab.url(rUrl);
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general this is correct, but there are a few simple mistakes.

1. On line 6, `var currentTab.url` is not valid syntax. Just call the variable something like `currentUrl`.
2. On line 6, it is `safari.application.activeBrowserWindow.activeTab` not `safari.application.activeBrowserWindow.currentTab`.
3. On line 8, `url` is not a function, it is a property. Just assign it with an equals.

This should work:

```
<script>
safari.application.addEventListener("command", performCommand, false);

function performCommand(event) {
    if (event.command == "translate") {     
        var currentUrl = safari.application.activeBrowserWindow.activeTab.url;  
        var rUrl = "http://translate.google.it/translate?u=" +  encodeURIComponent(currentUrl) + "&sl=auto&tl=it&hl=&ie=UTF-8";     
        safari.application.activeBrowserWindow.activeTab.url = rUrl;
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Hi Matt, thanks! Now the button in toolbar worked but doesn't load the current url. Probably here: encodeURIComponent(currentUrl) https://www.dropbox.com/s/uemccj6urji0vud/error.png

Comment: url google translate + current tab + &sl=auto&tl=it&hl=&ie=UTF-8 doesn't show

Comment: Make sure that "Access Level" is set to "All" in the extension builder.